# Converting a bunch XLSX files in a folder into CSV

Tags: vba, visual-studio

the catch is that the xlsx files have some Korean text which on converting to csv is changing to "??"

Comment: why the visual studio tag? Is this what you are using to handle the conversion? Do you have an existing script?

Comment: BTW—PowerShell might be a handier tool than VBA.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the contents of xlsx file from Korean to English as shown in below link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/excel.aspx
Then proceed to convert xlsx to csv.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider simply coding a loop saving as Unicode Text (*.txt) file format, and then changing the file extension to .csv

UTF-16 is useful if your Excel data contains any Asian characters e.g. Korean.

Note:

It is not fully compatible with ASCII files and requires some Unicode-aware programs to display this so be careful if exporting outside of Excel.

Information on options are discussed [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/04/24/convert-excel-csv/)

To continue quoting from there:

> How to convert an Excel file to CSV UTF-16 Exporting an Excel file as
>   CSV UTF-16 is much quicker and easier than converting to UTF-8. This
>   is because Excel automatically employs the UTF-16 format when saving a
>   file as Unicode (.txt).
>
> So, what you do is simply click File > Save As in Excel, select the
>   Unicode Text (*.txt) file format, and then change the file extension
>   to .csv in Windows Explorer. Done!
>
> If you need a comma-separated or semicolon-separated CSV file, replace
>   all tabs with commas or semicolons, respectively, in a Notepad or any
>   other text editor of your choosing (see Step 6 above for full
>   details).

Answer (score 0):

Every text file has a character encoding for a character set. You have to pick one.

If you pick one that doesn't support all the characters in the file, what would you like to happen? Replacing with ? is a commonly used option.

Picking UTF-8 for Unicode is a good choice for an Excel workbook (and almost all documents) because it uses the Unicode character set (as does VBA, BTW).

In any case, for a text file you have to communicate which encoding you use; And, for a CSV text file, whether there is a header row, what the field separator is, what the text qualifier is (quoting), text qualifier escape, line separator line characters, and column types are. (All of these are questions the Excel's text import wizard asks. Your users need the answers.)